# Android adding a layout to a tab

Tags: java, android

I've completed the tutorial on http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html so that now in my code, every activity has its own entry in the manifest and its own class such as....

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PetCareActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setText("This is the Pet Care tab");
        setContentView(textview);
    }
}
```

The problem is at this point, I can only do things like creating textView.  How would I add extra content within the tab, similar to https://market.android.com/details?id=com.bskyb.sportnews&hl=en

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. You pass the layout resource id to [setContentView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28int%29).

Comment: So say if I wanted to add a linearlayout within a tab, then buttons on top of that linearlayout, where would I actually put the code for this?  Within or in an XML file and reference that to submit it into my setContentView?